# How to decrease ipa size of my App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipa

I am currently working on app there is lot of images. all images size is near about 130mb. While i am creating build then getting 150mb size of ipa.

So my question is . What should i do for make less then 50mb ipa size.Is there any way to reduce my ipa size.

Hope anyone will help me.

Comment: I don't think you are giving enough information about the nature of your images. Have you tried to save the images out in a more compact format? For instance PNG-8 instead of PNG-24. Or can these images be replaced with more compact vector versions and rendered at run time?

Answer (score 2):

If you are iOS8+ go to your architectures, change it from "Standard (armv7s, arm64)" to "other" and just use arm64.

Every device from iPhone5s and beyond supports arm64.

So you'll just be missing out on iPhone4, iphone5(/c), iPad4 users, etc. For us this was less than 2% of our total users and was worth it because.... removing the armv7s arch from our app decreased the app size by **20MB** when we exported it to ITC. *It just optimizes solely on arm64 now.*

This allowed our other 98% of users to be able to download updates (or the app itself) without a Wifi connection which increased our total installs and well made up for the lost 2% of out-dated users.

---

For reference here is a compatibility chart:
[image]

Comment: Not the iphone 4S, iPhone 5, and older ipad 4 and older.

Comment: @KingofBliss Thank you, I've edited this into my answer! Not sure why I thought that was the case when I first posted this, docs clearly say otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider app thinning but this would only work on new ios 9 devices. Other ways is to download these images as and when required from the server and don't include everything in the bundle.

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

Answer (score 1):

Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html

Mostly check your assets and architectures you are supporting with. Also if your application is targeting iOS 8 and higher, you can remove 1x images from assets. Also, replace your launch images with launch storyboard xib file.